# Automating two sliders on one line

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate sliders on selenium, when i try to do it inside of my POM it moves one slider, stops, and then returns error "Element not interactable", when i try to code it procedurally using basicly same logic, both sliders move.

In both cases, locators are dynamic, and in both cases i used absolute Xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://phptravels.net/hotels/en/usd/dubai/29-09-2022/30-09-2022/2/3/1/TC')
driver.maximize_window()

mainSlider=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fadein"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span/span[3]')
size=mainSlider.size
w,h=size['width'], size['height']
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span/span[6]')
elem2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span/span[7]')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(elem, w*0.3, 0).perform()
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(elem2, w*-0.2, 0).perform()
```

**Above code works, while in next code that is part of POM only one slider moves**

**Base page method**

```
def drag(self, locSlider,locSlideLine, percX, percY):
    mainSlider=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, readConfig('locators', locSlideLine))
    size=mainSlider.size
    w,h=size['width'], size['height']
    elem = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, readConfig('locators', locSlider))
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(elem, w*percX, h*percY).perform()
```

**Call of base page method**

```
from pages.basePage import BasePage

class ResultPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def filter_and_choose(self):
        self.drag("slide_from_XPATH","slider_XPATH", 0.3,0)
        self.drag("slide_to_XPATH", "slider_XPATH", -0.2,0)
        self.click("hotel_detail_btn_XPATH")
```

**Test**

```
import pytest
from  utilities.get_data import data_getter
from pages.homePage import HomePage
from tests.baseTest import BaseTest

class TestHotelBooking(BaseTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("city, day, age, country,firstname,lastname,Email,Phone,Address,country,nationality,trav1title,trav1firstname,trav1lastname,trav2title,trav2firstname,trav2lastname,trav3title,trav3firstname,trav3lastname,childfname,childlname", data_getter('Sheet1'))
    def test_hotel_book(self,city,day,age,country):
        page=HomePage(self.driver)
        page.hotel_search(city,day,age,country).filter_and_choose()
```

Comment: Next day, sliders work normally without any intervention in code.

Comment: And the next day it does not work again.